# React.js Duplicate key and Unreachable code BUGS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Hi I'm learning React.js and I'm making a ChatApp right now. 
Here is my bug and codes.**

> ./src/App.js   Line 10:7:  Duplicate key 'currentUsername' 
>   no-dupe-keys
>
> ./src/components/ChatScreen.jsx  Line 35:5:  Unreachable code 
>   no-unreachable
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.To ignore,
>   add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Chatkit from '@pusher/chatkit-client'

class ChatScreen extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentUser: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const chatManager = new Chatkit.ChatManager({
      instanceLocator: 'v1:us1:1308c34d-00c3-4257-b1c3-647cf56fd5fa',
      userId: this.props.currentUsername,
      tokenProvider: new Chatkit.TokenProvider({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/authenticate',
      }),
    })

    chatManager
      .connect()
      .then(currentUser => {
        this.setState({ currentUser })
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('error', error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
    const styles = {
      container: {
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
      chatContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
      },
      whosOnlineListContainer: {
        width: '300px',
        flex: 'none',
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#2c303b',
        color: 'white',
      },
      chatListContainer: {
        padding: 20,
        width: '85%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
    }

    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        <div style={styles.chatContainer}>
          <aside style={styles.whosOnlineListContainer}>
            <h2>Who's online PLACEHOLDER</h2>
          </aside>
          <section style={styles.chatListContainer}>
            <h2>Chat PLACEHOLDER</h2>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default ChatScreen;
```

Could you help me?

Comment: For the second warning, it's because you have two `return` statement inside your `render` method. Delete the first one. You should also put your `const styles` outside your component. For the first warning, please provide `App.js` file code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First warning

> ./src/App.js Line 10:7: Duplicate key 'currentUsername' no-dupe-keys

You have a duplicate key in your state declaration

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUsername: '', 
      currentUsername: 'WhatIsYournameScreen',
    }
    this.onUsernameSubmitted = this.onUsernameSubmitted.bind(this)
  }
```

You need to remove either `currentUsername: ''` or `currentUsername: 'WhatIsYournameScreen'` line according to your needs.

### Second warning

> ./src/components/ChatScreen.jsx Line 35:5: Unreachable code no-unreachable

You have two `return` statements inside your `render` method. You need to delete the first one.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Chatkit from '@pusher/chatkit-client'

class ChatScreen extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentUser: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const chatManager = new Chatkit.ChatManager({
      instanceLocator: 'v1:us1:1308c34d-00c3-4257-b1c3-647cf56fd5fa',
      userId: this.props.currentUsername,
      tokenProvider: new Chatkit.TokenProvider({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/authenticate',
      }),
    })

    chatManager
      .connect()
      .then(currentUser => {
        this.setState({ currentUser })
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('error', error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        <div style={styles.chatContainer}>
          <aside style={styles.whosOnlineListContainer}>
            <h2>Who's online PLACEHOLDER</h2>
          </aside>
          <section style={styles.chatListContainer}>
            <h2>Chat PLACEHOLDER</h2>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
      container: {
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
      chatContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
      },
      whosOnlineListContainer: {
        width: '300px',
        flex: 'none',
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#2c303b',
        color: 'white',
      },
      chatListContainer: {
        padding: 20,
        width: '85%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
    }

export default ChatScreen;
```

Comment: I fixed all errors but I dont see my css codes. I just seeing html

Comment: I did send, you can see below

Comment: You have no error ? Because nothing's wrong with your code as I can see. I did run your code, css is working as expected

Comment: What!? How? here is my screen you can see https://ibb.co/TY4T5dW

Comment: Try this `this.state = {
      currentUsername: '',
      currentScreen: 'ChatScreen',
}`

Answer (score 0):

> ./src/components/ChatScreen.jsx Line 35:5: Unreachable code no-unreachable

This lint error is warning you that you have a return statement at the top of your render method, followed by code that will never execute below it. Ie, this code makes the rest of the function useless:

```
return (
  <div>

  </div>
)
```

> Duplicate key 'currentUsername' no-dupe-keys

This error is occurring in App.js, which you havn't shared with us. But it's telling you that you've given an object the property `currentUsername` twice. For example, maybe you have something like:

```
const myObject = {
  currentUsername: 'bob',
  currentUsername: 'alice',
}
```

Or are trying to create a component with the same issue:

```
<ChatScreen
  currentUsername="bob"
  currentUsername="alice"
/>
```

Comment: OKey I did delete return (
  <div>

  </div>
)

Comment: But I'm taking tgis err ./src/App.js
  Line 10:7:  Duplicate key 'currentUsername'  no-dupe-keys

Comment: You can find my App.js to bottom

Answer (score 0):

`ChatScreen.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Chatkit from '@pusher/chatkit-client'

class ChatScreen extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentUser: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const chatManager = new Chatkit.ChatManager({
      instanceLocator: 'v1:us1:1308c34d-00c3-4257-b1c3-647cf56fd5fa',
      userId: this.props.currentUsername,
      tokenProvider: new Chatkit.TokenProvider({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/authenticate',
      }),
    })

    chatManager
      .connect()
      .then(currentUser => {
        this.setState({ currentUser })
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('error', error))
  }

  render() {
    const styles = {
      container: {
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
      chatContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
      },
      whosOnlineListContainer: {
        width: '300px',
        flex: 'none',
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#2c303b',
        color: 'white',
      },
      chatListContainer: {
        padding: 20,
        width: '85%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
    }
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        <div style={styles.chatContainer}>
          <aside style={styles.whosOnlineListContainer}>
            <h2>Who's online PLACEHOLDER</h2>
          </aside>
          <section style={styles.chatListContainer}>
            <h2>Chat PLACEHOLDER</h2>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}




export default ChatScreen;
```

`App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import UsernameForm from './components/UsernameForm'
import ChatScreen from './components/ChatScreen'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUsername: '',
      currentScreen: 'WhatIsYournameScreen',
    }
    this.onUsernameSubmitted = this.onUsernameSubmitted.bind(this)
  }

  onUsernameSubmitted(username) {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username }),
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          currentUsername: username,
          currentScreen: 'ChatScreen'
        })
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('error', error))
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.currentScreen === 'WhatIsYourUsernameScreen') {
      return <UsernameForm onSubmit={this.onUsernameSubmitted} />
    }
    if (this.state.currentScreen === 'ChatScreen') {
      return <ChatScreen currentUsername={this.state.currentUsername} /> 
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hoş geldin</h1>
        <UsernameForm onSubmit={this.onUsernameSubmitted} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Code-only answers are eligible for deletion.